# Fading in an attribute with Jquery + accordion

Tags: jquery, regex, accordion, fadein, attr

I'm using jquery + the accordion plugin.  That's working great.  Now, I want another image on the page to change when the accordion selection change.  I've gotten that working too.  Here's the JQuery to make that happen:

```
//Triggers events on Accordion change
    $(function() {
        var accOpts = {
            changestart: function(e, ui) {
                 var src = "images/about/" + ui.newHeader.html().match(/[\w]+[_][o]/) + ".png";
                $("#poster").attr("src", src);
            }
        };
        $("#accordion").accordion(accOpts);
    });
```

Now that all that's working, I want the image to fade in, replacing the old one.  I tried implementing the fadeIn function like this: `$("#poster").attr("src", src).fadeIn(3000);`, but that doesn't work.  Any ideas on how I might modify this code to get that fadeIn working properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hide the image first before you fade it in:

```
$("#poster").hide().attr("src", src).fadeIn(3000);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/FDLqv/)**

To have a neater effect, you can fadeOut instead of abruptly hide the image. The key here is to use the callback parameter of the [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method to ensure the image totally dissapears before changing its source and fading it in:

```
$("#poster").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", src).fadeIn();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/3QHPZ/)**

Comment: Works great - thanks!  I like the effect it creates, but just out of curiosity, how would I have have the original image fade out as this one fades in.  The effect is pretty abrupt.

Comment: I've added an example with fadeOut.

Answer (score 2):

To crossfade images they both need to be on the page, so you can't just switch the source. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/FDLqv/)

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    changestart: function(e, ui) {
        var src = $(ui.newHeader).data('src');
        $("#posterHolder .poster").addClass('outgoing');
        $("#posterHolder").append('<img src="' + src + '" class="poster incoming" style="display:none;" />').show(1000,function(){
            $("#posterHolder .outgoing").remove();
            $("#posterHolder .incoming").fadeIn(2000).removeClass('incoming');
        });
    }
});
```